# WebStorm is not allowing code inspection in debug mode

Tags: javascript, debugging, mocha.js, webstorm

WebStorm (2017.1) is not allowing me code inspection.

I have some Mocha tests running and configured in WebStorm. I am using Node 6.10.

I place a breakpoint in the code and code execution stops at that point. However :

1. **I cannot place my mouse over a variable to see what its value is.**
2. **I cannot enter anything in the cursor in the debug console window to inspect it (the debug console window does not seem to let me enter anything).**

Without being able to inspect my debug code I am pretty much stuck, and WebStorm is useless to me.

The test runs like this. This is the command that is given in the console :

> /usr/bin/node --debug-brk=38590 --expose_debug_as=v8debug
>   /home/swe/Repositories/WebClient/code/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha
>   --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive --require ignore-styles --timeout 0 --ui bdd --reporter /home/swe/oliver/WebStorm-171.3780.79/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js
>   /home/swe/Repositories/WebClient/code/tests/utils Debugger listening
>   on [::]:3859

Also I cannot inspect variables in the variables window. It hangs at 'Collecting Data'. This is all I see :

[image]

Comment: mocha debugging (with `--compilers js:babel/register`) works fine for me. What Node.js version do you use? Sample project that shows up the issue plus idea.log would be helpful

Comment: hi lena, seems to be OK now. Strange.... anyway if it happens again I will post the logs (node version is the latest-ish = 6.10)